# GCC: Compiling with basic debbuging information added (flag -g) what are the effects on the performance?

Tags: c, performance, debugging, makefile

i recently checked some Makefiles made by some authors that are very skilled in this field (programming and such). Those makefiles are for programs compiled with the gcc compiler on linux systems.

In some of them i found the "-g" flag in the CCFLAGS and the LDFLAGS options included, even in the non debugging targets. I wanted to know what this does and found that it adds some basic debugging information to the code.

I am wondering what are the negative effects on the performance? Should i better remove them from my own non debugging targets or are the negative effects negligible when no debugger or profiler is actually used?

Comment: `are the negative effects negligible when no debugger or profiler is actually used`? better ask an oracle.

Comment: Benchmark your code with and without the option. Your question is far too broad to be answered in general. Best answer would be: "It depends".

Comment: @Marged No, `-g` does not disable any optimizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-g` parameter itself should not have negative effects on the performance of your program:

> GCC allows you to use -g with -O. The shortcuts taken by optimized
>   code may occasionally produce surprising results: some variables you
>   declared may not exist at all; flow of control may briefly move where
>   you did not expect it; some statements may not be executed because
>   they compute constant results or their values were already at hand;
>   some statements may execute in different places because they were
>   moved out of loops.

(see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.6/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options)

So you can combine `-g` and `-O` although you should be warned that the strange things mentioned above could happen. So altogether it does not make sense to combine release code with debugging symbols, unless you try to debug your code at your customers site. But when you do this you perhaps don't have an optimal debugging experience.

But keep in mind that debugging can considerably increase the filesize of your program.

If there are any sideeffects to be expected you can only benchmark this with your implementation, you can't transfer the knowledge gained by someone else to your code / algorithm.